# JMeter: I need to handle dynamically changing ID in URL (Get request). ID will get change on every load (Ajax)

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

Kindly suggest any way to extract those ID from JMeter.

**Request URL:**
https://**********/***/***/?_=1570625406235

Answer (score 0):

If you're really looking for the way of extracting this the relevant regular expression would be `=(\d+)`

Demo (assumes RegExp Tester mode of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener)

[image]

However this `1570625406235` looks like a [Unix timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) to me resulting into `Wed Oct 09 14:50:06 CEST 2019` in my time zone therefore instead of trying to extract it I would recommend parameterizing it using [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) which generates a current time in the Unix timestamp format

[image]

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept.